# Time Window Constraint in Vehicle Routing Problem by using Google OR-Tools - Solution is null

Tags: c#, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I have implemented VRPTW of Google OR-Tools. My Time Matrix is as follow

```
public long[,] TimeMatrix = {
               {0,5,20,10,0,5},
              {5,0,25,10,5,5},
              {20,25,0,30,20,20},
              {10,10,30,0,10,15},
              {0,5,20,10,0,5},
              {5,5,20,15,5,0}
}
```

And Time Window is

```
Depot - Time Window (8:00 AM to 6:00 PM) 
Loc1 - Time Window (2:00 PM to 3:00 PM)
Loc2 - Time Window (1:00 PM to 2:00 PM)
Loc3 - Time Window (2:00 PM to 3:00 PM)
Loc4 - Time Window (12:00 PM to 1:00 PM)
Loc5 - Time Window (3:00 PM to 4:00 PM)
```

And in minutes it is

```
public long[,] TimeWindows = {
               {0, 600},    // depot
              {360, 420},   // 1
              {300, 360},  // 2
              {360, 420},  // 3
              {240, 300},  // 4
              {420, 480},    // 5
            };
```

But its not working. The solution is null.

When i change time window array like this

```
public long[,] TimeWindows = {
              {0, 40},    // depot
              {5, 25},   // 1
              {20, 30},  // 2
              {10, 30},  // 3
              {0, 20},  // 4
              {5, 20},    // 5
    }
```

Then it worked. But i do not need this time window.

What am i doing wrong? Please suggest any solution?

Comment: Change your TimeMatrix numbers to match your TimeWindows.

Comment: I have changed TimeMatrix to this

{
0,365,320,400,0,425
5,0,325,400,275,425
20,385,0,420,290,440
10,370,330,0,280,435
0,365,320,400,0,425
5,365,320,405,275,0
}. But still solution is null.

Comment: Why are the TimeWindows number different from the TimeMatrix numbers?  For example one is 365 and the other 360.

Comment: In the dimension, did you force it to start at 0 ?

Comment: yes i was passing true flag to force start at 0. But when i changed it to false then it worked. @LaurentPerron